# Can't unlock Bitlocker Encrypted Drive

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, ntfs, bitlocker, raw

I have a BitLocker encrypted external HDD without any OS installed in it (have 2 partitions one NTFS other one BitLocker encrypted). I plugged it to pc with usb then i unlocked my drive on Win10 with my password as usual then i was copying the data from my unlocked BitLocker encrypted drive to another non-encrypted drive. Then power cut suddenly. After that i can't access my BitLocker encrypted drive anymore.

What I've tried:

- When i try to unlock that drive from Windows Explorer pop-up says "Encryption on this drive is not compatible with your Windows. Try to unlock it with newer version of Windows." without password and recoverypassword/recoverykey input options. But my Win10 is fully updated (1703)
- Tried Win7  popup came without asking any password "Failed to unlock the drive. No protector keys found in this drive."
- I also tried manage-bde -BitLockerdrive -protectors -get the output is "ERROR: No key protectors found". But drive seems like encrypted already.
- I tried repair-bde with 48 digits recovery password for recovering data to another HDD. Recovery done without any errors. Then did "chkdsk outputdrive: /f" it says "File system is NTFS. The first NTFS boot sector is unreadable or corrupt. Reading second NTFS boot sector instead. Unable to determine volume version and state. CHKDSK aborted." The disk shown as RAW and i can't access it.
- After that i also tried third party recovery tools for recovering data on the drive that created after repair-bde (decrypted RAW one). I recovered all my files without any corruption. But all of them shown as RAW files and had randomized names without folder structure. Somehow repair-bde can't transfer folder structure.
- I tried third party recovery tools on unaccessable BitLocker encrypted drive. It listed all my files with correct file names and folders and I can recover them but they are BitLocker encrypted and I can't open them. So folder structure on encrypted drive is not corrupted I think but I can't recover them because they are encrypted and I can't open any file.

I need folder structure, my files are too dispersed. What is the solution? Like repairing BitLocker encrypted partition somehow or unlocking it with recovery password somehow or recover encrypted files then recover them with recovery password somehow or recover files in RAW drive with folder structure? I need to recover my files without breaking folder structure. I don't know much about BitLocker or NTFS. I don't know if the file system, partition table, master file table, master boot record, boot sectors are corrupted.

Comment: Encrypted or not, HDDs do not handle power failure well (especially if it was performing a read/write operation when the power was cut). Since the files were encypted, they cannot be accessed without a tool that knows which "key" to use to decrypt the drive. [See this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0103d69b-53e9-4dd6-a808-203b087f819b/cant-unlockrepair-bitlocker-encrypted-drive?forum=win10itprosecurity) and [this](https://www.powerdatarecovery.com/data-recovery-resources/bitlocker-drive-encryption-recovery.html). If you have a backup of the data, I'd recommend a re-format

Comment: I am the first guy who asked on first link. Thirdparty tool that i used is the one in the second link. It succesfully recovered all files on the RAW disk that created with repair-bde as RAW files with randomized names, but without folder structure as i mentioned above. I also tried GetDataBack for scanning that bitlocker encrypted drive it shows the file structure 100%. I know power failure is serious problem but the files are not corrupted. I am trying to recover them without breaking folder structure.